# Installing WSO2 Developer Studio Fails

Tags: installation, wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I ran through the installation steps for installing WSO2 Developer studio using the offline set of steps.  I completed the installation but when I attempt to open any of the wso2 perspectives in eclipse I get errors such as the following:

```
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.6.0_29
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.javascript.product -keyring /Users/sowens/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.javascript.product -keyring /Users/sowens/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

Error
Mon Feb 25 16:30:26 PST 2013
Unable to create view ID org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer: An unexpected exception was thrown.

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.platform.ui.provider.FilterNestedProjects.getPathList(FilterNestedProjects.java:54)
    at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.platform.ui.provider.FilterNestedProjects.select(FilterNestedProjects.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerFilter.filter(ViewerFilter.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getFilteredChildren(StructuredViewer.java:921)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.getSortedChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$1.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.createChildren(TreeViewer.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalInitializeTree(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.internalInitializeTree(TreeViewer.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$5.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1517)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1443)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.preservingSelection(TreeViewer.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1404)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1510)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1690)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigator.createPartControl(CommonNavigator.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.ProjectExplorer.createPartControl(ProjectExplorer.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewPane.setVisible(ViewPane.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1245)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1198)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1597)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.createControl(PartStack.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.createControl(PartStack.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartSashContainer.createControl(PartSashContainer.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveHelper.activate(PerspectiveHelper.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.onActivate(Perspective.java:981)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:3713)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busySetPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:1115)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$16(WorkbenchPage.java:1099)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$19.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3814)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:3812)
    at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowPerspectiveHandler.openPerspective(ShowPerspectiveHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowPerspectiveHandler.openOther(ShowPerspectiveHandler.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowPerspectiveHandler.execute(ShowPerspectiveHandler.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.PerspectiveMenu.runOther(PerspectiveMenu.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.PerspectiveMenu$3.runWithEvent(PerspectiveMenu.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4125)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1457)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1480)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1270)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3971)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Any thoughts on what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

We have analyzed this particular code segment but it does not seems to have the capability to produce a NPE from there.

Thus we believe this NPE could be hiding the real cause and throwing this exceptions instead.

However We have made some performance improvements involving this particular class for the upcoming Developer Studio 3.0.0 release.

You can download the Developer Studio 3.0.0 RC1 preview P2 repo from [here](http://builder1.us1.wso2.org/~developerstudio/developer-studio/3.0.0/RC1/wso2-developer-studio_3.0.0.zip) and see whether your issue still persists.

Before starting Eclipse instance, please make sure that your Eclipse workspace location has necessary file systems permissions.

/Harshana